# Parse GeoPoint query slow and timed out using javascript sdk in node.js

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I have the following parse query which times out when the number of records is large.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("UserLocation");
query.withinMiles("geo", geo, MAX_LOCATION_RADIUS);
query.ascending("createdAt");

if (createdAt !== undefined) {
    query.greaterThan("createdAt", createdAt);
}
query.limit(1000);
```

it runs ok if UserLocation table is small. But the query times out from time to time when the table has ~100k records:

```
[2015-07-15 21:03:30.879] [ERROR] [default] - Error while querying for locations: [latitude=39.959064, longitude=-75.15846]: {"code":124,"message":"operation was slow and timed out"}
```

UserLocation table has a latitude,longitude pair and a radius. Given a geo point (latitude,longitude), I'm trying to find the list of UserLocations whose circle (lat,long)+radius covers the given geo point. It doesn't seem like I can use the value from another column in the table for the distance query (something like `query.withinMiles("geo", inputGeo, "radius")`, where "geo" and "radius" are the column names for GeoPoint and radius). It also has the limit that query "limit" combined with "skip" can only return maximum of 10,000 records (1000 records at a time and skip 10 times). So I had to do a almost full table scan by using "createdAt" as a filter criteria and keep querying until the query doesn't return results any more.

Anyway I can improve the algorithm so that it doesn't time out on large data set?